# Access Exchange Mails using EWS without C# code?

Tags: c++, exchangewebservices

Is there a way I can access the Exchange Mails/Calendars/Addressbook without .NET or non cross platform thing? I want to access them with C++ but on both MS and Linux. Their docs says it is possible but there is no any non C#/.Net example.

*EWS combines the functionality that is included in WebDAV and CDOEX, and provides logic that makes common scenarios such as calendaring workflows easy to implement. EWS is a SOAP-based XML Web service that can be accessed remotely from any operating system and any language that can send requests over HTTPS.*

Please share with me if there is any way or I'm missing something!
Thanks!

Comment: Please realize that the effort to access the MS Exchange Server has been a huge undertaking in the Linux community. As a for instance http://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000378.htm describes the process of connecting one of the mainstream email clients to an Exchange 2010 server.

Comment: I was looking fro Dev perspective. I don't want to use MAPI, I thought using SOAP would be a little breeze but then no docs. BTW I use TB for years and evolution failed me a lot:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that there are few examples outside the C# / Powershell realm. That being said, if you stick to plain EWS, it should be possible. I have no idea the WebServce access from C++ is anything similar to C#. In C# you point Visual Studio (or wsdl.exe) to the WSDL of the WebService and it will create a set of proxy classes which do all the SOAP handling.

If you don't have something similar with C++ you'll need to build the SOAP requests yourself.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119(v=exchg.140).aspx for a reference to the EWS operations and XML elements.

One thing you might want to utilize is the EWS Managed API. It has a nice tracing feature which dumps all the requests/responses to the console. So, you can write up a small test program and see what the request has to look like. This could help you building the EWS requests on the C++ side.

Comment: I will have to learn making soap requests to EWS. Thanks for explanation as well as a link